# How to set up cloth simulation for belt

Tags: cloth-simulation

So I have a coat and I wanted to put a belt on it. The problem is, cloth simulation goes weird especially on the belt slot part (Probably because the belt slot is too close to the edge of the belt but if I make the belt smaller it still occurs. Question is, how do I set up a cloth simulation for my belt so it doesn't glitch out?

[image: screenshot of the coat]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide any geometry to test?

Comment: Ok, I've added it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't pin the upper part of the belt which wraps around the belly? The belt slot part has no collision. That's the reason why the belt slips through it.

Comment: I thought the belt slot has collision because it is merged with the coat. Also If I pin the belt then there won't be a some sort of "tightening" effect that the belt produces. I tried to fake it as a temporary solution by making the coat's mesh looks like it has been tightened by the belt around the belly and then pin that part for the coat and the belt.